# System Settings > Privacy & Security > "Allow accessories to connect" section is not visible

Tags: macos, security, system-settings, accessories

I am running Mac Studio (Apple Silicon) on MacOS Ventura 13.2, which is the latest version as of writing.

For some reason, on this particular computer, **System Settings > Privacy & Security > "Allow accessories to connect"** section is not visible. However, it is visible on my MacBook Pro.

What might be the reason for this? I theorize that it may be because the Mac Studio has some external devices connected to it already (monitor, USB/Thunderbolt Hubs, iPad, etc), but I have not investigated this as I'd have to tear things down.

Comment: [Allow accessories to connect to your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-nz/guide/mac-help/mchlf779ae93/13.0/mac/13.0) "If you have a ***Mac laptop*** with Apple silicon, you have to approve new USB or Thunderbolt devices that you connect to your Mac." Emphasis added.

Comment: @user16145658 Good catch, thanks.

Comment: Mine is a MacBook Pro'19, Intel silicon. Also invisible.